# cannot draw multiple shapes on canvas when using clearRect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

when i use ctx.clearRect before drawing all objects only the last object is drawn (with updated chrome and firefox).
Everything is drawn without clearRect.

```
//in interval    
for(var i = 0;i<objects.length;i++){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    objects[i].draw();
}

function drawRect(x,y,w,h,fill){
    if(fill)
        ctx.fillRect(x-camera.x,y-camera.y,w,h);
    else
        ctx.strokeRect(x-camera.x,y-camera.y,w,h);
}

function square(pos,size){
    object.call(this);
    this.pos = pos;
    this.size = size;
    this.draw = function(){
        drawRect(this.pos.x,this.pos.y,this.size.x,this.size.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `clearRect` method call out of the loop body:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i].draw();
}
```

Otherwise, you will clear the canvas with the start of each loop iteration - which causes all objects apart from the last to be cleared.

Comment: i feel so stupid now, thanks for the response anyway

Comment: @eim64 Take a coffee break :) - if you feel ashamed about having asked this question, I don't mind deleting this answer ;)